# I keep getting an error while I'm installing firefox. How do I fix it?

Tags: software-installation

I'm trying to install some apps for my pi 3, and it keeps giving me this error:

```
E: Unment dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I tried inputted 'apt-get -f install' but it just gave me more errors:

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unabke to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg), are you root?
```

I'll accept any answers. Help?

Comment: will you accept `42`? ... lol

Answer (score 1):

please note the error message: **are you root?**

```
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg), are you root?
```

You have to prepend the commands with `sudo`, for example:

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt-get -f install
```

Comment: I typed in 'sudo apt-get -f install' and it installed something. However, at the end it said 'dpkg: error processing package perk-base (--configure); package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should reinstall it before attempting configuration'

Comment: @Sleeping Please edit your question and explain the (new) situation, or create a new question about it.