# Continued app installation problems with pi 3b

Tags: software-installation

I recently made [this post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/116213/i-keep-getting-an-error-while-im-installing-firefox-how-do-i-fix-it) where I asked for help with installing programs.

The error I had was:

```
E: Unment dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

So, naturally, I tried `apt-get -f install` and it gave me back an error. A user named [Ingo](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/79866/ingo) told me that I needed to put `sudo` at the beginning. I did, and this is where I am now.

When I execute the command, it tries and installs but when it's finished (or almost finished?) it says

```
dpkg: error processing package perl-base (--configure); package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should reinstall it before attempting configuration.
```

I'm not very good with programming, so I'm clueless to what this means... help?

Comment: What most of us would do in this situation is restore from your backup.

Answer (score 1):

The last error message stated `... you should reinstall it before attempting configuration.` So try to do that with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt update
rpi ~$ sudo apt install --reinstall perl-base
rpi ~$ sudo apt full-upgrade
```